# How to upload photos with React Native

Tags: react-native, file-upload, fetch, strapi

node v10.14.1
npm v6.4.1
strapi v3.0.0@13.0.1

I'm trying to upload a picture taken with a "PhotoUpload" component to Strapi.
Despite various tests, I get an error 500 from the server.

```
Insert_Files_Into_DataBase = () => {

const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("files:", this.state.image1); //Base64

this.setState(
  {
    ActivityIndicator_Loading: true
  },
  () => {
    fetch("" + NETWORK.SERVER_IP + ":1337/upload", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.props.userToken.jwt
      },
      body: formdata
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJsonFromServer => {
        alert(responseJsonFromServer + "Image1 OK!");
        this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading: false });

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading: false });
      });
  }
);
};
```

My "PhotoUpload" component allows me to retrieve the Base64 from the image. But it doesn't seem to work.

With Postman, everything works correctly

Comment: From where do you get that Base64 image source ? Can you also add a screenshot of how you are uploading photo with Postman?

Comment: Can you look into my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this on the iOS simulator? I find uploading only works for me on a real iOS device.

Comment: i'm using a real Android Device

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you are appending `files:` (with extra colon (:)). I think, you should append just `files` in the `FormData()` as:

`formdata.append("files", this.state.image1); //Base64`

This might be the case you are getting 500. If not also, you should append `files` instead of `files:`.

If this solves your problem, don't forget to hit upvote. :)

Comment: Are you sure, you have image data in `this.state.image1` ? 
Please log the `formdata` after appending the image and send it here.

Comment: Yes, by adding "console.log(this.state.image1);" after the appendix, I get  the BASE64 : /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWIC...

Comment: I meant, `console.log(formdata)`

Comment: I get a JSON containing the base64:

FormData {_parts: Array(1)}
AddAnnounce.js:98
_parts:Array(1) [Array(2)]
length:1
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:Array(2) ["files", "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBw…"]
length:2
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:"files"
1:"/9j/4AAQSkNvrR8eVIyEmi60Z60XlQ...
__proto__:Object {constructor: , append: , getParts: }

Answer (score 0):

I found a first mistake! 
I had simply forgotten the "`HTTP://`" in the address of my server.

Now, the server sends me back "true" but the image is not actually uploaded